# create user/group not working using curl

Tags: box-api

I am working on using box apis to create enterprise user and group. I am unable to create the user/group through curl or through java code as the request results in Forbidden error (403). Please note that the auth token has been created using enterprise admin credentials which could create the user/group in Box admin console.

Following is the curl command and its response :-

> curl --insecure https://api.box.com/2.0/groups -H "Authorization: Bearer AUTH-TOKEN" -H "Content-type: application/json" -d  "{"\"name"\": "\"family"\"}" -X POST -v

RESPONSE :-

```
> POST /2.0/groups HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.27.0
> Host: api.box.com
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Bearer <AUTH-TOKEN>
> Content-Length: 18
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 18 out of 18 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< S erver: nginx
< Date: Fri, 13 Dec 2013 13:04:52 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
< WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="Service", error="insufficient_scope", error_description="**The request requires higher privileges than provided by the access token."**
```

Thanks,
Alevi

Comment: Does your application have administrative scope turned on?  You may need to turn it on, and then re-authenticate yourself through OAuth2

Comment: Is your application enabled for admin-scoped tokens?

Comment: Hello Platform Boxer, Sorry for the delay in response. As suggested by  you, i enabled the administrative scope and the above curl command worked !!!! Thanks :) However, i need to do the same programmatically and i am unable to perform a similar action through java json object. Follwing is the code for your reference:-

Comment: JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();
jobj.put("\"name"\", "\"abcdef1"\");

Using the above jsonobject and passing it to the HttpUrlConnection now gives the bad request error..

Comment: Are you trying to create a new account in Box? Or are you just trying to take one of the users in your enterprise and upgrade them to be a co-admin?

Comment: Trying to create a new box enterprise user

Answer (score 0):

To call APIs that manage users you have to meet several permissions requirements.

1) The app you build has to have "Manage an Enterprise" scope (Set this up in your application management console in the "OAuth2 parameters"
2) The user logging into your app has to have co-admin permissions
3) The co-admin has to specifically be allowed to "manage users"

Unless you meet all those criteria, you won't be able to call the API to add a user.
If you do, it should be a simple POST to ./users with a json payload with the user object.  See http://developers.box.com/docs/#users-create-an-enterprise-user for an example CURL call

Comment: Hi Peter,
I use credentials of the enterprise admin. Does he not have privileges higher than the co-admin? Yes, what the api has specified is a simple curl which is not even working. Please refer to the additional quotes i put in my curl request ( "{"\"name"\": "\"family"\"}" ) as compared to the one suggested in the api example. Even though, i tried a similar request (working curl request) in my POST using java code, all i result in getting BAD Request (400) error. Please suggest.

Comment: The enterprise admin is basically like your super-admin, so yet, you'd have permission to do that.  Are you sure you've setup your app to have "manage an enterprise" scope in your app configuration OAuth2 settings?

Comment: Please add `re-authenticate yourself through OAuth2` to the answer. This should be done to make the change work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may just have the wrong slash.

Try this:

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/groups -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" -d "{\"name\”: \“my group\”}" -X POST
```

Comment: Hi Peter,In the example, i have used the backslash. Isnt there only one back-slash on the keyboard?

Comment: Yes, I believe there is only 1 backslash.  Maybe I read your initial post wrong, but I thought I tried to cut and paste your cURL cmd, and I had to change slashes to backslashes. you should probably also get rid of the -insecure param.  We require https, so that may be also causing problems.